# multi-select dropdown for categories and sub-categories

Tags: php

HI,

I have a two multi-select dropdown list, one is for category and another for sub-category. When i select categories from dorpdown list, corresponding sub-categories should be listed in another multiselect dropdown list.

Please send me link where this sample is given.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and php in a way similar to [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/change-dropdown-list-options-values-from-database-with-ajax-and-php.html)